# Scheduler client initiation failed -> Could not get handle to remote scheduler: Sched1_$_NON_CLUSTERED

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, rmi, quartz

I'm using Quartz 2.3.1

**RMI NON_CLUSTERED mode.**

```
    properties for the server are set as follow:
    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: Sched1
    org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: true
    org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryHost: localhost
    org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryPort: 1099
    org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.createRegistry: true

    org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true
```

**AND FOR CLIENT**

```
    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: Sched1
    org.quartz.scheduler.logger: schedLogger
    org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true
    org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: true
    org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryHost: localhost
    org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.registryPort: 1099
```

When I try to run the client I get the following exception:

> org.quartz.SchedulerException: Could not get handle to remote scheduler: QrtzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED [See nested exception: java.rmi.NotBoundException: Sched1_$_NON_CLUSTERED]

This is working in windows server using above properties file but it is not work in Linux(ubuntu) and gives above exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps :

Step 1: Add below property in schedular-server.properties :
        org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.serverPort = 1100

Step 2: Run below command in ubuntu:
        sudo rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false &

Step 3: Restart your java code (Schedular).